# Dynamically insert row in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to insert a row in the DataTable on button click.

Here's my html:

```
<table id="orders" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead bgcolor="#ADD8E6">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Normal Price</th>
                        <th>Discount %</th>
                        <th>Line Taxes</th>
                        <th>Final Price</th>
                        <th>Line Item Total</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
```

Here's how I am defining the datatable:

```
table = $("#orders").DataTable({
  ajax: {
url: "/api/lineitems?id=" + id,

dataSrc: ""
 },
  columns: [{
  className: "description",
  data: "product.description",
},
{

  data: "quantity",
  render: function(data, type, product) {
    var s = $('<select id="qty_dropdown" />');
    for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
      $('<option />', {
        value: i,
        text: i
      }).appendTo(s);
    }
    return s.prop("outerHTML");


  }
},
{

  data: "product.productPrice"
},
{
  data: "discount",
  render: function(data, type, product) {
    return "<div class='form-group'>" +

      "<input type='text' class='form-control'  value=\"" + data + "\"></input>" +
      "</div>";

  }
},
{
  data: "product.isTaxable",
  render: function(data, type, product) {
    if (data == true)
      return "<label><input type='checkbox' value='true'></label>";
    else
      return "<label><input type='checkbox' value='true'></label>";
  }
},
{
  data: "finalPrice"
},
{
  data: "lineItemTotal"

},
{
  data: "product.description",
  render: function(data, type, product) {

    return "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash js-delete' data-lineitem-id=" + data + "></span>";


  }
}
```

]
});

And here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function () {
       table.row.add([
            "dfdsgsgdfgd",
            "15",
            "1234",
            "10",
            "12",
            true,
            "12345",
            $("#product").val()
        ]).draw();
});
```

When I click on the button, I get the following error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=orders - Requested unknown parameter
>   'product.description' for row 0, column 0. For more information about
>   this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Can anyone tell me what I doing wrong here please.

Comment: You must insert data the same way as they are defined in columns.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like key value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you mean by that? Like key value pairs?

Yes, simply an object literal with the exact same layout as your `dataSrc`, or at least the same as those properties you define in `columns`:

```
table.row.add({
  quantity: 'foo',
  discount: 'foo',
  finalPrice: 'foo',
  lineItemTotal: 'foo',
  product: {
    description: 'foo',
    productPrice: 'foo',
    isTaxable: 'foo'
  }
}).draw()
```

---

The checkbox is not rendered properly because you define a checkboxs state by the `checked` attribute, not `value`. I.e

```
return "<label><input type='checkbox' checked></label>";
```

instead of

```
return "<label><input type='checkbox' value='true'></label>";
```

You can use `value` to store a value (!) but it does not change the `checked` state.

Comment: Thank you. This worked except for the isTaxable value. If I set it to true, the checkbox  is not checked. I tried setting it like this : isTaxable: true (without quotation) but it didnt render a checked box.

Comment: See update, this is because you are handling the checkbox inputs a little bit wrong.  You should use `isTaxable: true` if you evaluate with `if (data == true) in the render`.

Comment: Thank you very much david. Learned alot today. Thanks for your time.